# Protecting IC from voltage spikes

Tags: voltage, batteries, embedded, protection, decoupling-capacitor

I'm currently designing a PCB with a boosted audio amplifier. It is powered with a single li-ion cell with 3000mAh capacity. According to the datasheet of the audio amplifier, it is recommended to add a decoupling capacitor C1 as well as an inductor and a capacitor C2 to the inputs V_BATT and V_BOOST. Hereby, V_BATT is the input for the battery voltage and V_BOOST is the input for the booster of the audio amplifier.

In my application, I expect voltage spikes to occur as the battery also drives flickering high-power LEDs that draw 3A - 4A. The flicker rate (on off rate) is about 100Hz.

Now, I wonder if the capacitors and the inductor recommended in the datasheet suffice to protect the audio amplifier from the voltage spikes.

Datasheet:
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/TFA9896_SDS-1381317.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl8sxJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how much 100Hz buzz will you accept in your highpower audio?

Comment: The 100Hz shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: The answer depends on how you've filtered the power supply of the LEDs as much as on how you supply the audio circuit.

Comment: The LEDs are connected directly to the battery with an appropriate resistor. A Mosfet is controlled by another PCB and controls the LEDs via PWM.

Comment: Rather than try to protect your boost converter from the effects of the LEDs switching, consider putting some beefy capacitors in parallel with the LEDs so they don't produce so much ripple on the source voltage when they switch.